# Topology of spacetime in 2+1 dimension

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, differential-geometry, topology, topological-field-theory

In the book Quantum Gravity in 2+1 dimension by S. Carlip, in the second chapter (section 2.1), he comments that a compact 3-manifold with a flat time orientable Lorentzian metric and a purely spacelike boundary, necessarily has the topology $[0,1]\times \Sigma$, where $\Sigma$ is a closed surface that is homeomorphic to one of the boundary components.

Does this mean that all spacetime manifolds (flat) that we could allow in 2+1 dimension are necessarily of this topology (it seems to be a big restriction)?

Also, is it necessary for the boundary of a spacetime (for those that would have one) to be spacelike ? I have a rough argument (which I am not sure about) for this, that if we had a timelike boundary, in some coordinate system, we would have the boundary at some given value for the space co-ordinates which seems weird to me.

Answer (score 2):

Great question. I think these are the type of topologies that physicists like to deal with, certainly not true that this is all the spaces that can be written down .

For example if you demand global hyperbolicity then you will get something like what you describe.

In general, let $X$ be a smooth manifold, and $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$ be an atlas, let $\mathcal T$ be the sheaf of symmetric positive rank-2 tensors over $X$. If you can provide

- Initial conditions for Einstein equations on some subspace of $U_i$, and
- sections $g_i \in \mathcal T(U_i)$ that solve the Einstein equations with these initial conditions such that
- $g_i$ glue smoothly to a section $g \in \mathcal T(X)$

Then you're free to call the pair $(X, g)$ a spacetime.

Answer (score -1):

> Does this mean that all spacetime manifolds (flat) that we could allow in 2+1 dimension are necessarily of this topology (it seems to be a big restriction)?

Carlip is talking about *compact* manifolds. If you eliminate the requirement of compactness, then his statement is no longer true, and doesn't even make sense, because it refers to a boundary.

As a concrete example, it's possible for a flat spacetime in 2+1 dimensions to have the topology of Euclidean three-space. It just wouldn't be compact.

To see the point of what Carlip is talking about, consider the example of GR in 2+1 dimensions on a 3-sphere, which is compact. On the sphere, you're not going to be able to define a time orientation.

> Also, is it necessary for the boundary of a spacetime (for those that would have one) to be spacelike ?

Yes, I think there are counterexamples if the boundary is timelike. For example, consider a solid doughnut with the topology $B^2\times S^1$, where $B^2$ is a closed disc. Let the time orientation point around the doughnut, i.e., circling the doughnut hole. The boundary is timelike, and the topology does not have the form $[0,1]\times\Sigma$.

Comment: Why should it be true for compact manifolds? For example the procedure outlined in my answer provides an abundance of compact manifolds not of that topology.

Comment: @bianchira: I haven't read Carlip's argument, so I don't know. However, your answer doesn't provide a counterexample to Carlip's claim, it only lists conditions that would have to be satisfied by such a counterexample. If you think Carlip is wrong, it would be interesting to see a counterexample.

Comment: Example: Take any comstamt curvature 3 manifold then wick rotate.

Comment: @bianchira: Carlip's claim is about flat manifolds.

Comment: okay, take the constant curvature to be 0

Comment: I don't think this point is essential, but why would the reference to boundary exclude non-compact manifolds?

Comment: @BenCrowell It is in fact possible to define a time orientation on the 3-sphere. Whilst it's not "topologically trivial", its tangent bundle is, so there's no obstruction to defining smooth non-zero vector fields, metrics, n-forms, etc. See https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0609119.pdf.